# gdb: show corresponding lines in source and asm

Tags: assembly, gdb

When running gdb in TUI mode, showing source and assembly, is there an option to highlight the set of instructions mapping to a selected source line?

Comment: Don't think so, but maybe you can script it. Especially for optimized code  the relation might be unclear. godbolt can do that if all you want is static analysis.

Comment: @Jester: Thanks, I will take a look at godbolt.  I am debugging using some btraces recorded in gdb, and wanted a source/asm mapping to make the process go a little faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partially do it with GDB Dashboard.

https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard

From below screenshot you can see that the 1st call to `operator<<` in this line of code:

```
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

is mapped to 4 assembly instructions:

```
0x00000000004011a2  main()+28 mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x00000000004011a5  main()+31 mov    %eax,%esi
0x00000000004011a7  main()+33 mov    $0x404060,%edi
0x00000000004011ac  main()+38 callq  0x401070 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
```

They are highlighted with green color in Assembly section.

You can move to 2nd call to `operator<<` in the same line executing `ni` command several times and you will see the second mapping to 3 assembly instructions:

```
0x00000000004011b1  main()+43 mov    $0x401030,%esi
0x00000000004011b6  main()+48 mov    %rax,%rdi
0x00000000004011b9  main()+51 callq  0x401050 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, do you know how to shrink the console section? As I enter commands, it keeps growing, pushing all the other sections of the dashboard off the window.

Comment: This is probably configurable. Try `help dashboard` command or dashboard wiki on github: https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard/wiki.